# Generating Tables from SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I'm using MS Access 2013 and I have started learning SQL. I have written my SQL Database (all it does is make a bunch of tables) and I don't want to actually write anything in Access, I just want to bring in my SQL and request the Relationship Tables Diagram because my professor wants this particular diagram. Can someone tell me how to accomplish this? When I try to bring in my SQL it gives me errors saying that it was expecting INSERTS, DELETES, etc. but I don't have any actual data yet. I tried to look it up, but everything on Access and SQL is about making queries and I don't think that is what I'm after.

Comment: The term "sql database" is vague.  Oracle uses sql.  Is this an oracle database?

Comment: Yes. I wrote this DB for Oracle 9i and tested it with SQL*Plus.

Comment: It's just a SQL file. It literally consists of DROP TABLE X, CREATE TABLE X, DESCRIBE TABLE X. And it does this for a bunch of tables. I just want the diagram of the table relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Your database schema should have the following.

```
1 - one create database statement
2 - one to x create tables statements
3 - primary keys for the each table
4 - foreign keys to express relationships.
5 - other object when business requirements need them.
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema

Given this schema, the TSQL file can be loaded into any good modeling tool like [ERWIN](http://erwin.com/) to generate a diagram.

If you want to do it from MS Access, you can.  Behind the scenes, MS Access does support SQL in the query builder and you can use the table diagram window.

On the other hand, you can link MS Access to a SQL database (all tables) and still use the table diagram window.